# Is it possible to pull a native image (instead of a link) in IFTTT using webhooks and JSON?

Tags: json, ifttt

I'm using IFTTT to link social media platforms to Discord using Webhooks.
Webhooks use JSON and the nice thing is that I can be wherever, liking stuff on Pinterest or any given social media platform, and the webhooks auto-post the Discord so I'm not doing double work with content creation.

However, the JSON code only posts the URL to the social media platform, so instead of images I get URL links to my Pinterest. I'd prefer it if possible to use an image. The JSON image function doesn't grab the image (it breaks).

Is there a way to automatically post the image I'm concerned with instead of the URL?

```
{
  "content": "<<< {{PinURL}}>>>"
}
```

This is the JSON I have but the IFTTT "ingredients" don't provide a {{PinImage}}.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, IFTTT only provides access to a Pinterest's URL and description, among other things, but not the actual image.